# Vlookup not working

Tags: vlookup

Excel Test data

[image: Excel Test data]

Hi, I'm trying to use a Vlookup to match the column 'License' to the column 'case name(new)' and not having much luck, just comes up with N/A.

Here's the formula

```
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(E:E,4)&"*"&RIGHT(E:E,4),B3:F8,5,FALSE)
```

Can anybody see where I am going wrong?

Comment: Can you show the column ID's on your screenshot please? Is cas_id in column E?

Comment: any response.. please?